# Disallowing paragraph breaks inside environment

Tags: environments, paragraphs

An environment, `singlepar`, is supposed to contain a single paragraph. This means that there must be no paragraph breaks inside the code it wraps:

```
\begin{singlepar}
    Right.
\end{singlepar}

\begin{singlepar}
    Wrong.

    Wrong!
\end{singlepar}
```

My current approach is:

```
% \usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{singlepar}{}
{%
    % Ensure that this environment starts a new paragraph
    \par%
    % Save normal \par for later use
    \let\oldparforprivateuse\par%
    % Use of \par should abort the typesetting process
    \def\par{\typeout{DISALLOWED}\QUIT}%
    \ignorespaces%
}
{%
    % Issue a paragraph break
    \oldparforprivateuse%
}
```

However, it doesn't feel right. As for actual reasons, I have a feeling that this hack doesn't handle all cases. I believe that there could still be paragraph breaks; for example, by using `\let` to alias `\par`'s definition before the environment:

```
\let\takethis\par
\begin{singlepar}
    I'm gonna stab you in the back.
    \takethis
    Take this!
\end{singlepar}
```

I have checked the [`xparse` documentation](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) and there doesn't seem to be a way to inhibit paragraph breaks as is possible with macro arguments (paragraph breaks are disallowed in macro arguments unless they are preceded by a `+` in the macro declaration).

**How can paragraph breaks be totally inhibited in a section of the code?**

EDIT: By "inhibit", I mean that they abort the compilation so that one notices it. This is more about diagnosing my own mistakes when entering text.

Comment: You can't inhibit a primitive; so if there is `\endgraf` in the environment, you'd get a paragraph break. Similarly, any control sequence `\let` to the primitive `\par` will do the same. There's no way to know what control sequence names point to the `\par` primitive. Note that declaring a macro as non `\long` only disallows the *token* `\par` in its argument, but any control sequence `\let` to the primitive `\par` will be accepted.

Comment: @egreg -- but can't `\endgraf` be temporarily and locally redefined to trigger a warning, if not an error?  (have to be done with great care, of course.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, but one should disable also all other control sequences that have been `\let` to `\par` and this information is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want to hook in to `\par` that is the *end* of the first paragraph which really you want to allow, for a one para environment it is natural to allow

```
\begin{singlepar}

aaa

\end{singlepar}
```

which would not be allowed if you make `\par` an error.

What you don't want to allow is a second paragraph to *start* and that's `\everypar` There are still some concerns about things (re) defining `\everypar` but this will catch many cases, and allow the above example.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newenvironment{singlepar}
%{\def\par{\PackageError{pkg}{par DISALLOWED}{}\ignorespaces}}%
%{}


\newenvironment{singlepar}
{\everypar{\everypar{\PackageError{pkg}{par DISALLOWED}{}}}\ignorespaces}%
{}
\begin{document}

\begin{singlepar}

aaa

\end{singlepar}


\begin{singlepar}

aaa

b
\end{singlepar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your feelings are right. With

```
\begin{singlepar}
Wrong.\endgraf Wrong.
\end{singlepar}
```

you'd get a paragraph break and no error. The LaTeX format does

```
\let\endgraf\par
```

so making `\endgraf` equivalent to the primitive `\par`. Also `\@@par` is equivalent to the primitive `\par`, but it shouldn't bother you because it has `@` in its name.

You could say

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{singlepar}
 {%
  % Ensure that this environment starts a new paragraph
  \@@par
  % Save normal \par for later use
  % Use of \par should abort the typesetting process
  \def\par{\typeout{DISALLOWED}\QUIT}%
  \let\endgraf\par
 }
 {%
  % Issue a paragraph break
  \@@par
 }
\makeatother
```

but it wouldn't solve the problem, because some package could say `\let\foo\@@par` and then `\foo` in the environment would cause a paragraph break.

Since it's not possible to know what control sequences point to the primitive `\par` memory location for their meaning (like `\endgraf` and `\@@par`), the problem is not really solvable.

One could think to absorb the environment's body with a variant of `\NewEnviron` that makes a non `\long` macro (the standard action is to do like `\newcommand`), but this wouldn't solve the problem either. A non `\long` macro only disallows the *token* `\par` in its argument, but will happily accept `\endgraf` or any control sequence made equivalent to the primitive `\par`.

Finally, it's not possible to disable a primitive. You can hide it by redefining it, but control sequences already `\let` to it will continue to work.

Comment: I'm accepting David Carlisle's answer because it's "more powerful" at addressing the problem (besides making a good point: it's another paragraph starting that I need to disallow), but I feel sorry. Yours is excellent and your reasoning explains all of the caveats. Thank you! `:)`